# InstanceDouble(session) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[]= with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem with rspec behavior. I try to write test for service where I use `session`, for read some value and overwrite this value.

For example what I want to test

```
class CurrentCartService
  attr_reader :user, :session

  def initialize(user, session)
    @user = user
    @session = session
  end

  def cart_id
    { id: session[:cart_id] }
  end

  def assigne_cart_to_session
    session[:cart_id] = current_cart.id
  end
```

`spec`

```
describe CurrentCartService do
  let(:current_user) { user }
  let(:session) { double('session') }

  let!(:cart) { create(:cart) }

  subject { described_class.new current_user, session }

  before do
    allow(session).to receive(:[]).and_return(cart.id)
  end

  describe '#call' do
    context 'when user is not signed' do
      let(:user) { nil }
      it { subject.call }
    end
  end
end
```

`binding.pry`

```
session[:cart_id]
=> 574
```

```
session[:cart_id] = 123
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<InstanceDouble(session) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[]= with (:cart_id, 123)
```

How to fix this? I tried to write some `expect`

```
expect(session).to receive(:[])
```

But it does not work, it's still the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is telling you that your double received the message `[]=` with arguments `:cart_id` and `123` but didn't expect it.

Let's apply some basic logic. The problem is:

1. receiving a message
2. that wasn't expected

So, there are two things you can do to get rid of the message:

1. not send the message OR
2. tell the double to expect the message

The first one is easy: just remove line 14 which says `session[:cart_id] = current_cart.id` since that is the only place you are calling `[]=`. However, I don't think that is what you want to do.

Number two is also easy. There is a method called `expect` which allows you to tell a double to expect a certain message. So, all we need to do, is to set up an expectation.

Good failure messages are really important in a testing framework, and thankfully, RSpec *does* have good failure messages. The failure message should tell you how to move forward with your tests, and the message you quoted contains all the information we need:

- the name of the double that raised the failure (`session`)
- the name of the unexpected message that caused the failure (`[]=`)
- and even the arguments that were passed to the message (`:cart_id` and `123`)

All we have to do is, without even thinking about it, literally just copy&paste this information:

```
expect(session).to receive(:[]=).with(:cart_id, 123)
```

Or, if we want our tests to be a little less brittle and not hard-code the `123`, we could also do something like this:

```
expect(session).to receive(:[]=).with(:cart_id, instance_of(Integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the design you chose so I only reply on the error you get.

You allowed `session` to receive `:[]`.
And the error is that `session` received `:[]=`.

So you could allow `session` to receive `:[]`

```
  before do
    allow(session).to receive(:[]=).and_return(cart.id)
  end
```

NB : I wouldn't use `expect` which is solely for setting test expectations, not stubbing, which is what you want to achieve with `allow`.