# <InstanceDouble(ApiClient) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[] with (:id)

Tags: ruby, rspec, webmock

I am trying to mock an API get request (`get_organization`) to show a page with the organization's info. I am using an `ApiClient` service.

It works in practice, but when I try to stub the api request I get:

```
Failure/Error: if org_api_request[:id].present? && org_api_request[:id] == @org_id
       #<InstanceDouble(ApiClient) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[] with (:id)
```

I tried to add different versions of `expect(ApiClient).to receive([]).with(first_org[:id])` (with and without the `.with` statement) but all I get in response is `ApiClient does not implement: []`

The stub request:

```
stub_api_client(message: :get_organization, success: true, response: default_single_provider_org)
```

Organization Controller

```
def show
  @org_id = params[:org_id]

  org_api_request = api_service.get_organization(@org_id)

  if org_api_request[:id].present? && org_api_request[:id] == @org_id
    @org = org_api_request
  else
    flash[:alert] = "We were unable to connect to API"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**What I tried**

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560519/instancedoublesession-anonymous-received-unexpected-message-with)

```
stub = stub_api_client(message: :get_organization, success: true, response: default_get_provider_org_response)
allow(stub).to receive(:[]).with(:id)
```

(with and without the `.with(:id)`)

But I get this error:

```
the ApiClient class does not implement the instance method: []
```

Comment: What is `default_get_provider_org_response`?

Comment: What is `stub_api_client`? You're only showing us half of the puzzle.

Comment: In theory I think your approach looks good, **except** it appears your `stub_api_client` method is actually returning the **`ApiClient` class**, and not the `api_request` object -- which means your second stub is actually acting on the "wrong" object.